# Why C++ std::rand() has pattern?

Tags: c++, random

all

I am coming with a simple question. Please read my following codes first

```
int main()
{
    vector<double> arr1, arrr2;
    arr1.resize(120);
    arr2.resize(120);
    for(int i = 0; i < 120; i++)
    {
        double d1 = rand() % 100;
        d1 = d1/double(100);
        arr1[i] =d1;

        double d2 = rand() % 100;
        d2 = d2/double(100);
        arr2[i] =d2;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

In above code, I generate two random arrays (without any seed). I saved these arrays in the file and plot them as below:

[image]
From this image, I found that these two random series have similar trend in changing the number. e.g. these two series go up and down together from (x=57) to (x=60), and from (x=82) to (x=86), and etc..

May I know if I am simply mislead by the visualization, or there is really some correlation exist?

Many thanks in advance.

Best wishes

Long

Comment: Use `<random>`. The generators are generally fairly better.

Comment: The implementation of rand is not specified by C++.

Comment: The code in your question only initialises `arr1` and leaves `arr2` uninitialised.  Is this just a typo in your question or does the same error exist in your original logging?

Comment: "Why C++ `std::rand()` has pattern?" - the 'P' in PRNG stands for "pseudo".

Comment: Don't see the PRNG intialization in your code ? your main should start with something like: ` std::srand(std::time(0)); // use current time as seed for random generator`

Comment: @simonc Sorry that was a mistyping. My code is too complex thus I write an example here.

Comment: @alexbuisson - Using current time as a seed oftentimes is a bad idea.

Comment: I am not convinced there is any pattern at all.

Comment: @DavidHammen Care to elaborate? Why is it a bad idea? It's all over the place in tutorials...

Comment: Standard C rand() is notoriously low quality. Use a better PRNG library.

Comment: That `% 100` there also does not help your output, taking only the low bits of the result and introducing bias.

Comment: Out of 120 samples, you looked and found subsequences totaling only 7 samples where they vaguely "go up and down together." That's evidence of randomness if anything, not correlation. (But as others have noted, no it's not actually evidence of anything.)

Comment: @Kevin: Just because it's in tutorials doesn't mean it's good practice. `using namespace std;` is all over the place in tutorials. When not to use time as a seed: (1) You want N>1 random sequences. Use the equivalent of `srand(time())` for each and you'll have the same sequence, replicated N times. (2) You want cryptographically secure random numbers. Using time to seed a cryptographically secure PRNG destroys the security. (3) Monte-Carlo simulations. Suppose run #21375 of a Monte-Carlo simulation to test a design exposed a fatal design flaw. You'll want to be able to repeat that run.

Comment: @DavidHammen , I agree I just mentioned that as a PRNG's initialization example.

Answer (score 5):

You are doing a number of things wrong.

The number one thing you are doing wrong is to use `rand()`. There are plenty of good to excellent random number generators out there. `rand()` oftentimes doesn't even fall in the "good" category.

The next thing you are doing wrong is converting the integer result from `rand()` to a double via

```
double d1 = rand() % 100;
d1 = d1/double(100);
```

This discards the high level bits from the result of `rand()`. Even good random number generators can have problems with their low order bits. Bad random number generators such as the typical implementations of `rand()` almost guarantee this is the case. Instead divide by the largest possible result from `rand()`, `RAND_MAX` (cast to a double).

The next thing you are doing wrong is using the same pseudorandom sequence to generate two supposedly uncorrelated random number sequences. It's much better to use two different generators to do this. You simply can't do this with `rand()`. Use a better PRNG.

The final thing you are doing wrong is seeing a pattern where none may exist. You need to use more powerful techniques such as statistical correlation than your eyes. Or just use a better PRNG, one which has been tested in all kinds of ways to ensure that the results satisfy various tests of "randomness".

Comment: Hi, Daivid. Thank you for your answer. I appreciate it a lot. Since I am very new to this area, I have no idea which random number generator performs better than rand(). Would you mind to recommend some? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will have a small bias because RAND_MAX is not exactly divisible by 100, and you're throwing away all but log2(100) bits of precision, but the correlation you see could be very 
real. Standard C rand() is notoriously low quality, because it is often just a simple linear congruential generator, and those were known to be unacceptable for any serious use for decades, but library writers are lazy.

Find a library with a better PRNG algorithm. A lot of folks here will probably recommend something like Mersenne Twister, which is popular, but not the best. Modern generators use a careful combination of generator functions, including things like multiply with carry, xor shift, lagged fibbonacci (and even LCGs), and the combination of unrelated algorithms helps eliminate correlations.

Also check out chapter 7 of Numerical Recipes.

Comment: And not to toot my own horn in an answer, check out my PD PRNG library http://lcrocker.github.io/onejoker/randlib .

Comment: There's nothing wrong per se with linear congruential generators. They're never going to be anywhere close to the best, but they can be good enough to suit the purpose at hand. That's what chapter 7 of NR uses, for example. LCGs can be very bad with a bad choice of constants. One problem with many implementations of rand() is that they have a bad choice of constants. Another problem is that the sequence is typically rather short.

Comment: LCGs are fine combined with other generators (I'm talking about the latest edition of NR, not the decades-old one that touts plain LCGs). They might be fine for a simple game, but are totally unacceptable for Monte Carlo integration, simulations, even graphics. Just plot random points from an LCG and you'll see planes of correlation plain as day.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see evidence of a pattern. The human mind is a pattern matching machine and we see them everywhere, and randomness appears to us as a tendency to cluster, so in two random streams you can expect to find parts with seemingly matching trends.